# Use Raygun4Net in IIS site with sub application

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis, raygun

We have an IIS site (running on Windows Server 2012R2) which uses Raygun4Net for exception logging. As Raygun suggest, the logging is done from within the Application_Error handler in Global asax:

```
Sub Application_Error(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    Dim objRaygun As New RaygunClient()
    objRaygun.Send(AnException)

End Sub
```

The code compiles and runs fine, but a sub application within the IIS site (a virtual directory for file storage on a larger, but slower drive) has stopped working, as it cannot resolve a type at runtime:

> Could not load type 'Mindscape.Raygun4Net.RaygunHttpModule'.

I believe the virtual directory must be trying to pull the DLL from elsewhere, but I don't know where, as it sits in the same IIS Application pool and the virtual directory doesn't have a /bin directory.

NB: I have tried registering the DLL on my local machine using gacutil and referencing this assembly in the project... no change.

[image: IIS Site structure]

Happy to post more details, just let me know what is needed.

***Edit:*** manually adding a /bin directory containing the required DLL to the root of the virtual directory works, is there a way to do a Binding Redirect for a virtual directory?

Comment: The icon for `KeyHipsRepository` in the IIS tree suggests it is an application not a virtual directory. Applications use their own bin directory.

Comment: Yes, sorry, it is an application,not a virtual directory. As I mentioned in the question, manually adding a /bin directory works, but this isn't very clean as Visual Studio no longer supports sub applications, so this DLL would need to be manually updated if the version is ever changed...